# Count number of letter repetitions in a string

Tags: matlab

I am trying to find how many times each letter appears in a cell array.

I have to open this data file in Matlab

```
A 12 A 88
B 23 F 22
C 55 B 77
D 66 H 44
```

I named it `Thor.dat` and this is my code in Matlab

```
fid = fopen('Thor.dat')

if fid == -1
    disp ('File open not successful')
else
    disp ('File open is successful')
    mat = textscan(fid,'%c %f %c %f')
    [r c] = size(mat)
    charoccur(mat)        
    fclose(fid)
end
```

and the `charoccur` function is

```
function occurence = charoccur(mat)
% charoccur finds the number of times each character appears in a column

[row, col] = size(mat);
[row, ccol] = size(mat{1});

[mat] = unique(mat{i})
d = hist(c,length(a))
end
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: something like this: 
'A'    [2]
    'B'    [2]
    'C'    [2]
    'D'    [1]
    'F'    [1]
    'H'    [3]
    'W'    [1]

Comment: I edited your question title and re-formatted some parts to try and make it easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to do it using `unique` and [strcmp](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmp.html?searchHighlight=strcmp). Basically loop though the cell array and sum the number of occurence of each unique letters. Using `strcmp` gives a logical array of 0 and 1. By summing the 1s you get the total number of times a letter is found.

```
clear
clc


%// Input cell array
mat = {'A' 12 'A' 88;'B' 23 'F' 22;'C' 55 'B' 77;'D' 66 'H' 44;'W' 11 'C' 9;'H' 3 'H' 0};

mat = [mat(:,1) mat(:,3)]

%// Find unique letters
UniqueLetters = unique(mat);

%// Initialize output cell
OutputCell = cell(numel(UniqueLetters,2));

%// Loop through each unique letter and count number of occurence
for k = 1:numel(UniqueLetters);
    %// 1st column: letter
    OutputCell(k,1) = UniqueLetters(k);

    %// 2nd column: sum of occurences
    OutputCell(k,2) = {sum(sum(strcmp(UniqueLetters{k},mat)))};

end

OutputCell
```

`OutputCell` now looks like this:

```
OutputCell = 

    'A'    [2]
    'B'    [2]
    'C'    [2]
    'D'    [1]
    'F'    [1]
    'H'    [3]
    'W'    [1]
```

Hope that helps get you started!

**EDIT:**

As per your comment, for the initialization of the output cell array:

```
OutputCell = cell(numel(UniqueLetters,2));
```

I create a Nx2 cell array, in which N (the number of rows) is the number of unique cells identified by the call to `unique`. In my example above there are 7 unique letters, so I create a 7x2 cell array to store:

1) In column 1 the actual letter

2) In column 2 the number of times this letter is found in `mat`

Comment: Thanks a lot. But when I ran this code, it gave me an error: ??? Error using ==> cell.unique at 52
Each element in A must be a single-row text array.

Comment: You don't need to use unique first, if you just hold the counts in a vector big enough to index off of any valid character.  But it doesn't sound like the goal is to get frequency by counting characters, but by parsing an already-existing frequency table.

Comment: You need to work only with the text elements from you `mat` cell array.

Comment: @BenVoigt oh I did not see it like that maybe I'm wrong indeed.

Comment: Or I could be the one misunderstanding.  Hopefully the question gets clarified.

Comment: could you please tell me what you did over here: OutputCell = cell(numel(UniqueLetters,2));

Comment: Well I have the above data file, and the instructions are to count the number of times each character appears in the cell. Only the characters nt the numbers, i.e. column 1 and 3. Hope this clarifies the question

Comment: I edited the question to clarify this point hope this is clearer now.

Comment: so @Logan is this any clearer with the edit? Do you need more help?